# How to change the text of a label when a radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, html

What I don't understand is why does my code not change the text of the label when the radio is selected?

This is what is suppose to happen:

[image]

Which when 'Fahrenheit to Celsius' is selected the first image should be true (the text of the first and second label should change)

When 'Celsius to Fahrenheit' is selected the second image should be true (the text of the first and second label should change)

What I'm guessing is my problem is with the if ($("input:to_celsius").val() == "true") statement but I don't quite know why it's wrong.

***Current error message: 
{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 69,
  "colno": 30
}

```js
"use strict";
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };

var clearTextBoxes = function() {
    $("#degrees_entered").value = "";
    $("#degrees_computed").value = "";
};

window.onload = function() {
    $("#to_celsius").onclick = toCelsius;
    $("#to_fahrenheit").onclick = toFahrenheit;
   $("#degrees_entered").focus();
};

// Change the text of label 1 and 2 when the radio 'Celsius to Fahrenheit' is selected and clears all other inputs
var toFahrenheit = function() {
    if ($("#to_fahrenheit").val() == "true") {
        $("#degree_labl_1").text("Enter C degrees");
        $("#degree_label_2").text("Degrees Fahrenheit");
        clearTextBoxes();
    }
}

// Change the text of label 1 and 2 when the radio 'Fahrenheit to Celsius' is selected and clears all other inputs
var toCelsius = function() {
    if ($("#to_celsius").val() == "true") {
        $("#degree_labl_1").text("Enter F degrees");
        $("#degree_label_2").text("Degrees Celsius");
        clearTextBoxes();
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 450px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}
h1 {
 color: blue;
 margin: 0 0 .5em;
}
main {
    padding: 1em 2em;
}
label {
 float: left;
    width: 10em;
 margin-right: 1em;
    
}
input {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
#convert {
 width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Convert Temperatures</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="convert_temp.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<main>
    <h1>Convert temperatures</h1>    
    <input type="radio" name="conversion_type" id="to_celsius" checked>Fahrenheit to Celsius<br>
    <input type="radio" name="conversion_type" id="to_fahrenheit">Celsius to Fahrenheit<br><br>
    <label id="degree_label_1">Enter F degrees:</label>
    <input type="text" id="degrees_entered" ><br>
    <label id="degree_label_2">Degrees Celsius:</label>
    <input type="text" id="degrees_computed" disabled><br>
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert" /><br>   
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use jQuery and I don't see it loaded in your html. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: It also looks like you're not using jQuery selectors correctly. For example `input:to_celsius` should be `input#to_celsius` or just `#to_celsius`. https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

Comment: @sallf I added '<script src="jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>' to my HTML document.

Comment: Try leaving that jQuery script and looking at my next comment. Your selectors all need to be fixed. Mostly by adding a `#` to signify they are id's (like `#degree_labl_1`).

Comment: @sallf the edits have been changed. all id's are now listed as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues in your code.

Looks like you are trying to use jQuery here, but in your case you are overriding the jQuery `$` function with a custom function. **So in effect you are not using jQuery here by calling the $ function** but using pure javascript selectors

```
var $ = function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
};
```

With a function declaration as above, you can select elements only by Id and the Id **should not** be prefixed with  #

`$("#degree_label_1")` won't work here

`$("degree_label_1")` will work.

So I suggest changing the $ function declaration to something like below.

```
var $ = function(selector) {
            return document.querySelector(selector);
    };
```

Here I changed `document.getElementById` -> `document.querySelector` so that selectors are more flexible (You can use any css selectors like "#id", ".classname" etc)

As we are not using jQuery here, the below code will not work. In jQuery, its correct but there are syntax differences in accessing the dom in plain javascript

```
$("#to_fahrenheit").val() == "true"
```

One way to implement the same is..

Assign values to the radio button inputs

```
<input
      type="radio"
      name="conversion_type"
      id="to_celsius"
      value="f_to_c"
      checked
    />Fahrenheit to Celsius<br />
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="conversion_type"
      id="to_fahrenheit"
      value="c_to_f"
    />Celsius to Fahrenheit<br />
```

and check the value

```
$("#to_fahrenheit").value == "c_to_f"
```

Same applies to the below line. There's a typo as well (Missed an e in degree_lab<strike>e</strike>l_1)

```
$("#degree_labl_1").text("Enter F degrees")
```

should be changed to

```
 $("#degree_label_1").textContent = "Enter F degrees"
```

Complete code would look like below.

```js
"use strict";
      var $ = function(id) {
        return document.querySelector(id);
      };

      var clearTextBoxes = function() {
        $("#degrees_entered").value = "";
        $("#degrees_computed").value = "";
      };

      window.onload = function() {
        $("#to_celsius").onclick = toCelsius;
        $("#to_fahrenheit").onclick = toFahrenheit;
        $("#convert").onclick = convert;
        $("#degrees_entered").focus();
      };

      // Change the text of label 1 and 2 when the radio 'Celsius to Fahrenheit' is selected and clears all other inputs
      var toFahrenheit = function() {
        if ($("#to_fahrenheit").value == "c_to_f") {
          $("#degree_label_1").textContent = "Enter C degrees";
          $("#degree_label_2").textContent = "Degrees Fahrenheit";
          clearTextBoxes();
        }
      };

      // Change the text of label 1 and 2 when the radio 'Fahrenheit to Celsius' is selected and clears all other inputs
      var toCelsius = function() {
        if ($("#to_celsius").value == "f_to_c") {
          $("#degree_label_1").textContent = "Enter F degrees";
          $("#degree_label_2").textContent = "Degrees Celsius";
          clearTextBoxes();
        }
      };

      var convert = function() {
        var conversiontype = $(
          '[name="conversion_type"]:checked'
        ).value;
        var enteredValue = Number($("#degrees_entered").value);
        if (conversiontype === "f_to_c") {
          $("#degrees_computed").value = ((enteredValue - 32) * 5) / 9;
        } else {
          $("#degrees_computed").value = (enteredValue * 9) / 5 + 32;
        }
      };
```

```css
body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        background-color: white;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 450px;
        border: 3px solid blue;
      }
      h1 {
        color: blue;
        margin: 0 0 0.5em;
      }
      main {
        padding: 1em 2em;
      }
      label {
        float: left;
        width: 10em;
        margin-right: 1em;
      }
      input {
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
      }
      #convert {
        width: 10em;
      }
```

```html
<h1>Convert temperatures</h1>
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="conversion_type"
      id="to_celsius"
      value="f_to_c"
      checked
    />Fahrenheit to Celsius<br />
    <input
      type="radio"
      name="conversion_type"
      id="to_fahrenheit"
      value="c_to_f"
    />Celsius to Fahrenheit<br /><br />
    <label id="degree_label_1">Enter F degrees:</label>
    <input type="text" id="degrees_entered" /><br />
    <label id="degree_label_2">Degrees Celsius:</label>
    <input type="text" id="degrees_computed" disabled /><br />
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert" /><br />
```

If you want to use jQuery, you should remove below function declaration

```
var $ = function(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id);
    };
```

And modify your code as follows.

```js
"use strict";
var clearTextBoxes = function() {
  $("#degrees_entered").val("");
  $("#degrees_computed").val("");
};

window.onload = function() {
  $("#to_celsius").on("click", toCelsius);
  $("#to_fahrenheit").on("click", toFahrenheit);
  $("#convert").on("click", convert);
  $("#degrees_entered").focus();
};

// Change the text of label 1 and 2 when the radio 'Celsius to Fahrenheit' is selected and clears all other inputs
var toFahrenheit = function() {
  if ($("#to_fahrenheit").val() == "c_to_f") {
    $("#degree_label_1").text("Enter C degrees");
    $("#degree_label_2").text("Degrees Fahrenheit");
    clearTextBoxes();
  }
};

// Change the text of label 1 and 2 when the radio 'Fahrenheit to Celsius' is selected and clears all other inputs
var toCelsius = function() {
  if ($("#to_celsius").val() == "f_to_c") {
    $("#degree_label_1").text("Enter F degrees");
    $("#degree_label_2").text("Degrees Celsius");
    clearTextBoxes();
  }
};

var convert = function() {
  var conversiontype = $(
    '[name="conversion_type"]:checked'
  ).val();
  var enteredValue = Number($("#degrees_entered").val());
  if (conversiontype === "f_to_c") {
    $("#degrees_computed").val(((enteredValue - 32) * 5) / 9);
  } else {
    $("#degrees_computed").val((enteredValue * 9) / 5 + 32);
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 450px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

h1 {
  color: blue;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
}

main {
  padding: 1em 2em;
}

label {
  float: left;
  width: 10em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

input {
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#convert {
  width: 10em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<h1>Convert temperatures</h1>
<input type="radio" name="conversion_type" id="to_celsius" value="f_to_c" checked />Fahrenheit to Celsius<br />
<input type="radio" name="conversion_type" id="to_fahrenheit" value="c_to_f" />Celsius to Fahrenheit<br /><br />
<label id="degree_label_1">Enter F degrees:</label>
<input type="text" id="degrees_entered" /><br />
<label id="degree_label_2">Degrees Celsius:</label>
<input type="text" id="degrees_computed" disabled /><br />
<label>&nbsp;</label>
<input type="button" id="convert" value="Convert" /><br />
```